# How to convert org.neo4j.graphdb.Releationship to a SDN Relationship entity?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How can i convert a neo4j org.neo4j.graphdb.Releationship object to a spring data neo4j Relationship entity without loading the object again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use autowired *Neo4jTemplate*:

```
template.load(rel, YourRelationshipModel.class)
```

Note that additional data will be loaded if your relationship nodes are annotated with *@Fetch*.

Comment: You can also use `template.projectTo(rel, YourRelationshipModel.class)`